# How do I make 3 random circles appear and refresh without overlapping?

Tags: java, animation, overlap

I currently have a program that draws 3 circles randomly, then every second it refreshes and the circles appear in a different spot. The point is to not have them overlap. This is what I have so far. However, it works until the circles actually overlap. When this happens, it freezes. If anyone could help me I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks! :)

```
rX = randy.nextInt(width - fudgeX - diameter);
    rY = randy.nextInt(height - fudgeY - diameter);
    Bx = randy.nextInt(width - fudgeX - diameter);
    By = randy.nextInt(height - fudgeY - diameter);
    Gx = randy.nextInt(width - fudgeX - diameter);
    Gy = randy.nextInt(height - fudgeY - diameter);

    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillOval(rX, rY, diameter, diameter);

    BR = distance(rX, rY, Bx, By);

    while(BR < diameter)
    {
        Bx = randy.nextInt(width - fudgeX - diameter);
        By = randy.nextInt(height - fudgeY - diameter);
        distance(rX, rY, Bx, By);
    }

    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillOval(Bx, By, diameter, diameter);



    GR = distance(rX, rY, Gx, Gy);
    GB = distance(Bx, By, Gx, Gy);
    while(GR < diameter || GB < diameter)
    {
        Gx = randy.nextInt(width - fudgeX - diameter);
        Gy = randy.nextInt(height - fudgeY - diameter);

        distance(rX, rY, Gx, Gy);
        distance(Bx, By, Gx, Gy);
    }
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.fillOval(Gx, Gy, diameter, diameter);


    repaint();  
}

public double distance(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
    int changeX = x1 - x2;
    int changeY = y1 - y2;

    int squareX1 = (int) Math.pow((double)changeX, 2.0);
    int squareY1 = (int) Math.pow((double)changeY, 2.0);

    double d = Math.sqrt(squareX1 + squareY1);

    return d;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem that you are having? It seems to me that you are just asking us to complete this task for you.

Comment: Something like `Rectangle` or `Ellipse2D` have functionality to determine if two instances are overlapping

Comment: No, sorry. I am trying to get them to not overlap but it doesn't work, it just freezes. I don't want people to complete it, I already did. My version was working but for some reason it stopped working and I don't know why. I was asking people if they new why the program wouldn't work.